# How to make runtime changes to a Vaadin component after loading

Tags: vaadin

How can I change a Vaadin `h1` element dynamically using a timer after the page is navigated to from another Vaadin page?

navigate

```
start.addClickListener(e->{
    ActorCallsHandler.ach.startGame();
    UI.getCurrent().navigate(Playboard.class);
});
```

class

```
public class Playboard extends VerticalLayout
{
    private H1 timer;

    public Playboard() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException{
        generateGUI();
    }

    private void generateGUI(){
      //h1 element that should alter using a timer after page load
      H1 timer = new H1(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work, you need to use either the Push or Polling functionality of Vaadin so that changes can be sent to the client at any time instead of only in the response to a request that is triggered by some user action.

I would recommend that you check out the documentation for the Push feature at https://vaadin.com/docs/v13/flow/advanced/tutorial-push-configuration.html.